# Database client version mismatch in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, version, database, phpmyadmin

I use Ubuntu 14.04.1 Desktop and in PhpMy Admin I see this:

Database client version: `libmysql` - 5.5.**50**

But when I do this in the terminal:

```
mysql -V
```

I get ver. 5.5.**52**

Also in Synaptic Package Manager, when I go to "Databases", I see both `mysql` server and `mysqlclient` are 5.5.**52**. 
And in "Libraries" I see libmysqlclient18 also 5.5.**52**

Comment: Is it causing a Problem? Perhaps it's just a bug in phpmyadmin

Comment: What does `show variables like '%version%';` (inside mysql) gives you?  That *should* be how phpmyadmin gets it.

Comment: In the terminal I've got 5.5.52. But PhpMyAdmin still shows 50. But again, it shows 52 as a server version. But below that where it says "Database client" it shows 50.